# how to design PlayerActivity layout in each inch device

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to be my Player Activity in the way that main things show user(such as play button ,rewind,forward ,cover ,date) and other things show when user scroll activity in all device with each inch size.I do that in way that I get screen height of device in pixel and give to relative layout programmatically and other things put below of this relative layout.Is that true?

Answer (score 1):

if you ask about how to support different screen size it is devices

you should not add any `layout_width` or `layout_height` fixed size

and use weights in linear layout

Use best practices in dimensions use “dp” and in text size use “sp”.

Use nested layouts for better control and to make your activity xml less complex

You can make two designs one for big screens and one for small ones.

it is for layout , I hope it will help you .